# Echo a 3 dimensional array with foreach statement in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have seen all the questions that are relative with mine, and still didn't find any soloution to my 'simple' problem. I have a 3dimensional array and i just want to display the results. But when it's tome to echo the `. "<td>".$person ['job']."</td>"` i am getting errors. Any advice thnx

```
$people= array(

array(
    "name" => "Jennifer Kimbers",
    "age"=>"45",
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "city" => "Seattle",
    "state" => "Washington"),
        array(
            "job"=>"web developer"
        ),

array(
    "name" => "Rodney Hutchers",
    "age"=>"55",
    "email" => "def@gmail.com",
    "city" => "Los Angeles",
    "state" => "California"),
        array(
             "job"=>"data developer"
         );

echo "<table>"
    ."<th>FullName</th>"
    ."<th>Age</th>"
    ."<th>Email</th>"
    ."<th>City</th>"
    ."<th>State</th>"
    ."<th>Job</th>";

 foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo "<tr>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['name'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['age'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['email'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['city'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['state'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['job'] . "</td>"
        . "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: The input array has 4 items with different structure. Is this the correct input?

Comment: I think the structure of your array is not complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array structure is slightly off, in

```
array(
    "name" => "Jennifer Kimbers",
    "age"=>"45",
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "city" => "Seattle",
    "state" => "Washington"),  // Close bracket here
        array(
            "job"=>"web developer"
        ),
```

This indented properly is

```
array(
    "name" => "Jennifer Kimbers",
    "age"=>"45",
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "city" => "Seattle",
    "state" => "Washington"),
array(
    "job"=>"web developer"),
```

so your loop is trying to use this as two separate bits of data and the second one doesn't contain a lot of the fields you are expecting.

You need to make sure you close the array elements in the right place / add the job to the same element as the rest of the data...

```
array(
    "name" => "Jennifer Kimbers",
    "age"=>"45",
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "city" => "Seattle",
    "state" => "Washington",  // Move ) after the job
    "job" => "web developer"
),
```

If you need that extra level of arrays, then you could make it a list of jobs...

```
array(
    "name" => "Jennifer Kimbers",
    "age"=>"45",
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "city" => "Seattle",
    "state" => "Washington",
    "jobs" => array( "title" => "web developer")
),
```

The to display them

```
foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo "<tr>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['name'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['age'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['email'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['city'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $person ['state'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>";
    foreach ( $person['jobs'] as $job ) {
         echo $job . "/";
    }
    echo "</td>"
        . "</tr>";
}
```

although this way you will end up with a trailing `/` after the job title, it shows the principle.  You could instead of the inner `foreach()` loop use...

```
echo implode("/", $person['jobs']);
```

Comment: Look at the end of his entire array, does feel right?

Comment: @Hardood, it is possible that in copying the code to the question there has been a typo.  If the typo was in the original code I'm not sure it would get to the output to throw an error there.

Comment: Nigel Ren, i actually want to use `array(
    "name" => "Jennifer Kimbers",
    "age"=>"45",
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "city" => "Seattle",
    "state" => "Washington"),
array(
    "job"=>"web developer"),` cause my project requires 3 dimensional array

Comment: Suppose that my array is ok how can i display the results with foreach statement

Comment: I've added some more examples for using an extra level of the array.

Comment: I think that in `. $job['title'] . "/";` it's something wrong ? It is returning me `syntax error, unexpected '.' ` Also you have forgotter one `" ` in  `"jobs" => array( "title => "web developer")`

Comment: Sorry should have been `echo $job['title'] . "/";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215100/discussion-between-program21-and-nigel-ren).

Comment: So the solution is to fundamentally change the incoming data?

Comment: @mickmackusa, it's not incoming as such, it's data hardcoded in the script.